# What are the consequences of the retargeting aspect of the Battlemind's Lightning Rush power on enemy area or close blasts or bursts?

Tags: dnd-4e, psionics, interrupt, battlemind

[Lightning Rush](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=2634) is one of the battlemind's featured powers:

It's augment 2 (as an immediate interrupt) states:
Hit: 2[W] + Constitution modifier damage, and you become the target of the triggering attack.

[This thread](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/26630885/Lightning_Rush_and_BlastsBursts?pg=1) has some inconclusive discussion about the A2 causing retargeting of zones.  More commentary [here](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/22464381/Enders_Game_-_the_Battlemind_Handbook&post_num=7#391275401).

Therefore, given the following scenario, what happens?

1) An enemy wizard is in the middle of a nice featureless 8x8 room (the new 10 foot standard). The party is all clustered together by the door.

2) The wizard wins initiative and drops "fireball" on the party, triggering the Battlemind's lightning rush.

3) The battlemind, using her II, rushes forward 4 squares (heh) and successfully hits the wizard.

Who gets hit, with what? Why? (Cite your sources)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The battlemind steps in and **replaces a single target** in the list of those attacked by the `Fireball`; **and (most likely) invalidates that attack against her** by shifting out of the area of effect before it happens.

> `Lighting Rush` Immediate Interrupt (from pg 49 of PHB3):
>   ...
>   Trigger: An enemy within 5 squares of you targets an ally with an attack.

From the *Rules Compendium* pg 105, under **Area Powers**:

> **Origin Square**:  An area power's origin square is a single square that can be some distance away...
>    **Targets**: An area power targets specific individuals within the power's area of effect. For example, the power might target "each creature in the burst."...
>   *Multiple Targets*: If an area power has multiple targets and includes attack rolls or damage rolls, the attack rolls are made separately against each target, but a single damage roll is made against all the targets.

So:

- the Wizard casts `Fireball`

  - chooses an origination square for the `Burst 3` and targets "each creature within burst".
- the Battlemind, now that the trigger of "targets an ally" condition is met,

  - declares the use of her immediate interrupt `Lightning Rush` with `Augment 2`

    - Specifically, she uses the *targeting of the cleric* as the trigger.
- the `Fireball` is put on hold
- the Battlemind shifts adjacent to the Wizard

  - attacks the Wizard for 2[W] + Con
  - on a hit, the battlemind becomes a target *instead of the cleric*
- the `Fireball` is now resolved

  - the Battlemind is now targeted instead of the cleric
  - Most likely, as the Battlemind shifted, she left the `Burst 3` of the `Fireball` and thereby invalidated the attack *against her*.
  - Her intercession on behalf of the cleric had no effect on the rest of the party, though, unless she killed the wizard so the `Fireball` didn't happen.

The `Close Blast` will follow similar steps. For a `Close Burst`, though, the chance for the Battlemind to invalidate the attack by moving out of the area of effect is pretty much impossible, as she will be adjacent to the Wizard.

Comment: Now that I've written that, I'll got check out the thread you linked and see if I can figure out if I'm wrong... `:)`

Comment: That looks right to me.

Comment: Looks like the controversy at the end of the forum post (pg 3) centered around the text _become **the** target of the triggering attack._ I didn't change my answer, though. Since it triggers off the targeting of a single ally, it is that targeting that the Battlemind becomes the target of.

Comment: Just seen this post, and I'm not saying its wrong, but I play a Battlemind in LFR up to level 13 so far.  The way it's always been ruled with me is that after the Lightning Rush attack has been resolved the triggering burst/blast is then re-placed by the caster so the Battlemind is in it.  The caster also copped an opportunity attack from me if it was ranged/area attack.  You can imagine I did take advantage of this from time to time :P