# Does a double attack described as "make an X attack against two creatures" violate a defender's mark?

Tags: dnd-4e, mark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do marks interact with dual attacks?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/how-do-marks-interact-with-dual-attacks)

The Yuan-Ti as referenced [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/12957/if-a-battlemind-and-her-cleric-companion-are-the-target-of-two-attacks-by-a-yuan) makes a slam attack against a defender and a non-defender as a single action.

Would that "single action" which involves two attacks (with distinct damage rolls) violate the defender's mark?

Comment: This looks very similar to  http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4893/how-do-marks-interact-with-dual-attacks/4906

Comment: When considering vote-to-close as a duplicate of "How do marks interact with dual attacks" that there is a subtle difference, that dual attacks often say things like "target: one or two creatures" in the attack power, where as this question is about a power that is not an attack, but that grants the use of an attack power, twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume that the Yuan-Ti is using Double Attack in order to "make a slam attack against a defender and a non-defender as a single action"

> Double Attack (standard, at-will)  Poison
>   The yuan-ti anathema makes two slam attacks, each against a different target.

Each of the attacks made possible is a separate attack. This power grants action economy - do a pair of things that normally would each be standard actions, for the cost of a standard action. The power does not help work around defender marks.

This differs from a Blast or Burst which is both a single action and a single attack and so can be used to work around defender marks.